# An problem of irrational number approximation by rationals

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $\alpha$ is a positive irrational, and $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive real, are there $m,n$(non-negative integers) such that $$|\alpha-(2m+1)/(2n+1)|<\epsilon/(2n+1)?$$ 
If they exist, are there infinitely many $m,n$?
It seems in this case the Dirichlet approximation theorem can not be used directly.

Comment: This question turns out to be a simple one after I recognize the proper use of diophantine approximation rule. See also here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291052/is-it-possible-to-approximate-irrational-by-fractions-with-denominator-and-numer