# Irrational number approximation

Tags: approximation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Serge Lang Undergraduate Analysis exercise:

> (a) Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Show
>   that there exist integers $m, n$ with $n > 0$ such that $ \left|
>  m\alpha - n \right| < \epsilon$.
>
> (b)In fact, given a positive integer $N$, show that there exist
>   integers $m, n$ and $0 < m \leqq N$ such that $\left| m\alpha - n
>  \right| < 1/N$.

Similar question: [An problem of irrational number approximation by rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611643/an-problem-of-irrational-number-approximation-by-rationals)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I have never heard about diophantine approximation before. I'm going to learn it. And will do more search before asking next time.

Comment: So what? Is Serge Lang's *Undergraduate Analysis* meant to be read only by those whe did study it?

Comment: *I'm going to learn it.* --- A good place to begin, which is about as elementary as you'll be able to find (without being so trivial as to not get anywhere), is Chapter 6 (starts on p. 81) in [**Numbers: Rational and Irrational**](http://users.auth.gr/siskakis/Niven-NumbersRationalAndIrrational.pdf) by Ivan Niven.

Comment: In the book: THEOREM 6.5. Given any irrational number $\lambda$, there are infinitely many rational numbers $m/n$ in lowest terms such that $-\frac{1}{n^2}<\lambda-\frac{m}{n}<\frac{1}{n^2}$.
It is what i'm looking for.